# Why async function in node js hides all data instead of specifed?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
userSchema.methods.toJSON = async function(){
    const user = this
    const userObject = user.toObject()
    delete userObject.password
    delete userObject.tokens
    return userObject
}
```

but when I use normal function it works all good

```
userSchema.methods.toJSON = async function(){
    const user = this
    const userObject = user.toObject()
    delete userObject.password
    delete userObject.tokens
    return userObject
}
```

I am confused about the cause.
I would be grateful to know about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because when you define a function like you did:

```
userSchema.methods.toJSON = function(){
  const user = this
  const userObject = user.toObject()
  delete userObject.password
  delete userObject.tokens
  return userObject
}

//..and then call

userSchema.methods.toJSON();
```

and call the function, the result you expect is `userObject`. However, if you add the `async` syntax to the function the return of the function will be a `Promise` object with the `userObject` as the resolve of the `Promise` object.

So if you want to get the `userObject`:

```
userSchema.methods.toJSON = async function(){
  const user = this
  const userObject = user.toObject()
  delete userObject.password
  delete userObject.tokens
  return userObject
}

// And if you want to access your user object, you do this...

userSchema.methods.toJSON().then(function(userObject) {
  //...work with user object here
  console.log(userObject);
  //...
});
```

check this out for more https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-es-6-typescript-promises-examples/